# Create a box out of two geolocation coordinate points

Tags: java, ios, node.js, google-maps, geospatial

[image]

I have two geo coordinate `CLLocationCoordinate2D` points (P1 & P2) and I'd like to create a box that is perpendicular to the line joining them (the red box).

How can I get the four coordinates bounding this box?

Comment: I am using node.js and Google Maps API, just in case you guys know of a library that already does that.

Comment: Turf.js has a buffer method that should get you started

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try it out! :)

Comment: It worked! I just posted an answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@iant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439194/iant), I've been able to generate the bounding box (polygon actually) using [turf](http://turfjs.org/). Here is the code I used:

```
turf = require("turf")

var line = turf.lineString([
[-122.1381719, 37.4687134],
[-122.0300914, 37.331695]
]);

var unit = 'miles';
var buffered = turf.buffer(line, 5, unit);
var tolerance = 0.03; // increase tolerance to reduce polygon segments
var simplified = turf.simplify(buffered, tolerance, false);
```

[image]